# Errors when trying to run npm install discord.io winston -save

Tags: javascript, json

I was trying to run npm install discord.json winton -save and it returns in a bunch of errors.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'discord.io',
1 verbose cli   'winston',
1 verbose cli   '-save' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.14.0
4 verbose npm-session aece4781a47c67bb
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3ms
8 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 27ms
9 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json
9 verbose stack Unexpected token � in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{
9 verbose stack �name�: �miobot�,
9 verbose stack �...'
9 verbose stack     at parseError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:452:11)
9 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:104:26)
9 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:51:5
9 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16
9 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:54:3)
10 verbose cwd C:\Users\Fatal\Desktop\discordbot
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "discord.io" "winston" "-save"
13 verbose node v11.14.0
14 verbose npm  v6.7.0
15 error file C:\Users\Fatal\Desktop\discordbot\package.json
16 error code EJSONPARSE
17 error JSON.parse Failed to parse json
17 error JSON.parse Unexpected token � in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{
17 error JSON.parse �name�: �miobot�,
17 error JSON.parse �...'
18 error JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
18 error JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that is an actual npm package? I found this you can try not sure it's the same package you are looking for

```
npm cache clean -force
```

Then try and re run your npm install

Comment: Sadly, this did not solve the problem but caused more errors. Line 18 seems to say the issue best.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try that if that doesn't work. Can you add in your package.json file to the post so I can see it?